# How to obtain a handle to device driver

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver

I want to get a handle to a device driver using its name, like \Device\MyDriver. Is it possible to do it without using the symbolic link exposed?
The reason I ask is because I have an ACL applied to the \Device\MyDriver and a different one applied to the symbolic link "MyDriver". The one applied to the symbolic link is very restrictive and doesn't allow anyone to read. While the one applied to the device itself allows Administrators to read from the device.

I tried to use the following code:

```c
const wchar_t* driverName = L"\\\\?\\globalroot\\Device\\MyDriver
HANDLE driver = CreateFile(driverName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

However I couldn't get a handle. Any help? Or from user land the only way to get a handle is via the symbolic link?

Comment: driver object can not be opened  from user mode. you can not get handle for it. from another side absolute unclear what you try do at all. *only way to get a handle is via the symbolic link?* - of course no.

Comment: _the only way to get a handle is via the symbolic link?_ : YES. See articles like [Userland/Kernel communication – DeviceIoControl method](http://ericasselin.com/userlandkernel-communication-deviceiocontrol-method)

Comment: It's interesting that @RbMm says of course no and Castorix says YES. So? I read that article, but it doesn't mean I can't do it in a different. RbMm I said what I'm trying to do. Avoid the ACL. So what other options do I have? Any reference?

Comment: @Castorix - no, this is absolute false. if we can open some object via symbolic link - we can open it and by "direct" name

Comment: @Diego - you can not open driver object from user mode. and anyway this is senseless. assume you open it (got handle) and what next ? you can open device object. the name "MyDriver" is confused. so this is device or driver ? if device - yes, open it have sense. *However I couldn't get a handle* - first what you need do in this case - call `GetLastError()` and `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` and post result here

Comment: Access is denied... So, @RbMm what are the other options besides the symbolic link?

Comment: @Diego - how is symbolic link here related at all ? you got Access is denied from device. all

Comment: *symbolic link is very restrictive and doesn't allow anyone to read* - this is also wrong. the Security descriptor on symbolic link affect only - are you can open it via `ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject` and query it target. this not affect any if you open another object via symbolic link (here it SD not play role at all). error access denied not form symbolic link but from device object

Comment: @RbMm sorry but your English doesn't compute. If you can't help, or understand English, is fine. Go back and read what I wrote. Otherwise thank you for not answering my question and spamming it.

Comment: @Diego - symbolick link not related to your problem at all. what security descriptor was on symbolic link not play any role here. you can se yourself - you try open device "direct" via *"\\\\?\\globalroot\\Device\\MyDriver* (ok, here yet *globalroot* symlink, but if you use `NtOpenFile` with `\\Device\\MyDriver` you got the same result) and got access denied. your **device** object not allowed open it.

Comment: Of course you  can open drivers from User Mode : read the article ,MSDN, SDK samples, etc.... I did it thousands of times to send IOCTL codes with [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol)

Comment: @Castorix - you absolute mistaken. you can not open driver object from user mode. you can open device object. are you understand difference between driver object and device object ?

Comment: The OP question is : **How to obtain a handle to device driver** The answer is CreateFile on a symbolic link + DeviceIoControl to send IOCTL codes

Comment: @Castorix - what is *device driver* ? i dont know ? exist *driver object*, exist *device object*. exist *file object*. we can create *file object* on some *device object*

Comment: See MSDN  _"sends a control code directly to a specified device driver"_

Comment: @Castorix - anyway this is terminology error at begin and name *MyDriver* is confused (this is actually **device name** but not **driver name** ) and we can not open not driver, result of "open" device was not handle to device but handle to file on this device. and symbolic links here not play any role at all. access denied from device object

Comment: @Castorix, a Driver object (e.g. for ntfs.sys) has no parse procedure, so `ObOpenObjectByName` opens a handle for it directly. But from user mode, we need to call `NtCreateFile` or `NtOpenFile`, leading to `IoCreateFile[Ex]`. In this case the I/O manager passes an opaque open packet in the `ObOpenObjectByName` call, which is meant to be updated by the parse procedure of a Device object, `IopParseDevice`. If the packet doesn't get updated, as it won't be when opening a Driver object, the I/O manager closes the handle and fails the create with `STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH`.

Comment: It bears reiteration that the security on the SymbolicLink object has no relevance here. The Object Manager only opens a SymbolicLink object directly if we call `ObOpenObjectByName` with the type restricted to the SymbolicLink object type, such as via the `NtOpenSymbolicLinkObject(PHANDLE, ACCESS_MASK, POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES)` system call, and this type has only one access right: `SYMBOLIC_LINK_QUERY`. This has nothing to do with calling `IoCreateFile` (`NtCreateFile`, `NtOpenFile`, etc), for which the Object Manager will simply traverse a SymbolicLink object to its target.